# Use filter to return the words from a list of words which start with a target letter

Tags: python, lambda, filterfunction

```py
def filter_words(word_list, letter):
    return filter(lambda word: word[0]==letter,word_list)

l = ['hello','are','cat','dog','ham','hi','go','to','heart']
filter_words(l, 'h')
```

Expecting the ouput as ['hello', 'ham', 'hi', 'heart'] but the output is <filter at 0x261e956f340>

Comment: filter returns a generator, not a list. You'd have to iterate through the generator to get the list `list(filter_words(l, 'h'))`

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

> filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator expression
> (item for item in iterable if function(item)) if function is not None
> and (item for item in iterable if item) if function is None.

One way to see the output is to simply print it:

```
print(*filter_words(l,'h'))
# hello ham hi heart
```

If you were expecting a list, you need to explicitly a list:

```
list(filter_words(l,'h'))
# ['hello', 'ham', 'hi', 'heart']
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a list from `filter_words`  instead of filter object.

```
def filter_words(word_list, letter):
    return list(filter(lambda word: word[0] == letter, word_list))
```